# Propiedades en css

Tags: css

Estoy comprendiendo css y sus estilos pero tengo una duda de principiante y es que no comprendo como memorizar todas sus propiedades que consejo me pueden dar se que esta no es una plataforma para este tipo de preguntar pero no se que hacer no conozco otra

Comment: acá un libro de bolsillo y lo mas importante es practicar mucho: https://websitesetup.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/wsu-css-cheat-sheet-gdocs.pdf

Comment: No las memorices, úsalas y conforme las vayas requiriendo irán quedando en ti, siempre ten a la mano sitios web como el de mozilla developer, pero en serio de nada sirve que trates de memorizarlas (existen cientos de ellas)

Comment: ok de verdad me asustan porque hay milies